# Guitar tablatures typesetting with tabs over #9 and double hitting notes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, music

Many previous posts give clue on [how to strike a chord](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/guitar-chords/), with each of the finger placements on a guitar. Also, other posts even state [how to do a note by note progression](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/guitar-tablatures-typesetting) like [clemens](/users/5049/clemens)
shows for stairway to heaven.

All this is not enough for me. I want to make a tablature of John Frusciante's [Murderers](http://www.e-chords.com/tabs/john-frusciante/murderers). The double problem is:

- how to show notes that are above the 9th tab?
- how to show chords that strike in more than one note in a tablature?

Comment: maybe this can be solved with [lilypond](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-fretted-strings)? RTFM!

Comment: no upvotes on question, perhpas I should remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has already been answered to some extent by `clemens` with his additional last comments on that other post on [guitar tablature typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/guitar-tablatures-typesetting).  This is just a way of tackling the issue and to solve the problem with more detail and later on it may be proper to close or erase this post, due to lack of attention or perhaps usefulness.

Summing up, *it's possible to do tablatures*.

The two answers are, again by `clemens`:

- `\Str{2}{11}` means eleventh fret of the second string
- `\Notes\str{6}{7}\Str{3}{6}\en` is a two-note chord

Still, it'd be neat to get a cue on the underlying logic to other additional elements in this code. **How can the spacing between notes be controlled?** We need to combine the `\hsk` / `\sk` elements together with `\STr` `\Str` `\str`. How would one combine them so that the notes appear the closest together?

This `mwe` tries to show an approximation but still fails. Because the first two combinations of notes are close to the following but not so with the next ones...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex,graphicx}

% custom clef
\newcommand\TAB[1]{%
 \setclefsymbol{#1}{\,\rotatebox{90}{TAB}}%
 \setclef{#1}9}

% internal string choosing command
%  #1: string (a number from 1--6)
%  #2: finger
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@str[2]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\@strerror
  \or\def\@strnr{-1}%
  \or\def\@strnr{1}%
  \or\def\@strnr{3}%
  \or\def\@strnr{5}%
  \or\def\@strnr{7}%
  \or\def\@strnr{9}%
  \else\@strerror
  \fi
  \zchar\@strnr{\footnotesize#2}}
% \@strerror could be defined to issue some warning/error

% User level commands
\newcommand\STr[2]{\@str{#1}{#2}\sk}  % with a full note skip
\newcommand\Str[2]{\@str{#1}{#2}\hsk} % with a half note skip
\newcommand\str[2]{\@str{#1}{#2}}     % with no skip
\makeatother
\begin{document}

(0:35)

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{music}
 \instrumentnumber{1}
 \nobarnumbers
 \TAB1
 \setlines1{6}
 \startpiece
   \Notes\hsk\str{1}{7}\Str{5}{9}\en
   \Notes\str{1}{9}\Str{5}{10}\en
   \Notes\str{1}{7}\Str{5}{9}\en
   \Notes\str{1}{9}\Str{5}{9}\en
  \endpiece
  \end{music}

\end{document}
```