# MusixTex Tablature notation system

Tags: musixtex

I would like to benefit from Tablature notational system of musixtex. Unfortunately the numbers are displayed as squares.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\Largemusicsize
\setlines16             
\setstaffs1{1}
\setclefsymbol1{\tabclef}
\nobarnumbers
\let\extractline\leftline
\startextract
\Notes \tab{5}{3} \tab{4}{0} \tab{4}{2} \en
\bar
\Notes \tab{4}{3} \tab{3}{0} \tab{3}{2} \en
\bar
\Notes \tab{2}{0} \tab{3}{2} \tab{2}{0} \en
\endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

will be compiled as follows

[image]

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.
Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please see [this musiXTeX TAB answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49156/106187) for help

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I hope it's not too late to answer my solution. Like John I had the same problem. But also I had mixed the `musixtex` and `songs` packages. It seems that doesn't work compiling with `pdflatex`, but does with `latex`.This is my `music.tex` example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etex}

% for "songs" package
\noversenumbers 
% \songcolumns{2}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\lyricfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\printchord}{\it\small}
\afterpreludeskip=-18pt
\beforepostludeskip=-8pt

\songsection{Canciones para Guitarra}
\begin{songs}{}
  \beginsong{Sin tu latido}[by={\small Fernando delgadillo},
  cr={Powered by LaTeX and Songs & MusiXTeX packages, transcribed in 2020}]

  % From "musixtex" package
  % Some guitar tablature notation:
  \begin{music}
    \smallmusicsize
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol1{\small\tabclef} % and a TAB clef
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setname1{\tabstringfnt\baselineskip=1.5\internote%
    \vbox{
    \hbox to\parindent{\hss e\hss}%
    \hbox to\parindent{\hss B\hss}%
    \hbox to\parindent{\hss G\hss}%
    \hbox to\parindent{\hss D\hss}%
    \hbox to\parindent{\hss A\hss}%
    \hbox to\parindent{\hss E\hss}}}
    % \let\extractline\leftline % left aligned
    % \generalmeter{\meterC} % Puts the metric type in the tablature diagram
    \startextract
    \notes \tab{4}{3} \tab{3}{0} \tab{3}{2}\en
    \bar
    \notes \tab{2}{0} \tab{3}{2} \tab{2}{0}\en
    \bar
    \notes \tab{2}{1} \qp \qp\en
    \endextract
  \end{music}

  % From "songs" package
  % Some chords diagrams:
  \gtab{A}{1:X02220} \gtab{E}{1:022100} \gtab{D}{1:XX2320} 
  \gtab{Bm}{1:X(24432)} \gtab{C#m}{4:X(13321)} \gtab{E7} 
  {1:020100} \gtab{Bm7}{1:X(24232)} \gtab{F}{1:(133211)}

 % Some lyrics:
\beginverse\newchords{verso}\memorize[verso]
  \[A]Hay algunos que d\[E]icen
  bla bla bla...
  \endverse

  \beginverse\newchords{estribillo}\memorize[estribillo]
  Ay, amor \[Bm]mío, \[C#m] qué terriblemente abs\[E7]urdo es estar v\[A]ivo, bla bla bla..
  \endverse

  \beginverse
  {\nolyrics Final chords: \[A] \[Bm7] \[A] \[D] \[F] \[A]}
  \endverse

  \endsong
\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

To correctly compile and have an pdf output, from consol I run the comands:

1. `latex music.tex`
2. `dvips music.dvi`
3. `ps2pdf music.ps`

I'm using MikTeX (v2.9.62) and TeXMaker (v5.0.3) in Windows 10, but I made a simple `musixcompiler.bat` batch file in order to make a little bit fast the process and delete the aux files, so I can run from consol >`musixcompiler.bat music.tex` (both files must be in the same folder).

`musixcompiler.bat`

```
@echo off
cls
echo MusiXTeX Compiling
latex %1.tex
dvips %1.dvi
ps2pdf %1.ps
DEL /F /Q *.mx1
DEL /F /Q *.dvi
DEL /F /Q *.ps
DEL /F /Q *.log
DEL /F /Q *.aux
echo Finished!!!!
```

Hope it has been helpful. This was my result:

[image: resultado]

Answer (score 2):

I saved the example as test.ltx and executed

musixtex test.ltx

and it worked fine.  So I think you're not "compiling" properly.