# Guitar Strumming Pattern in Latex

Tags: pattern, music, songs, songbook

I want to make a guitar song book with Latex and i would like to add some Strumming Patterns. Do anybody have a idea how to make Strumming Pattern with the Arrows up and down and the numbers under them, like in ultimate guitar (e.g. https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/van-morrison/star-of-the-county-down-chords-1040988). Also it should be possible to create a 3/4 or 5/4 tact or even a Shuffle rymthm.
Thanks for your help.

PS: For some reason i cant use the new tag "Guitar Strumming Pattern" because you need 300 reputation to do so

Comment: I think most users here have no objection, i.e. are fine with you writing a guitar book. However, if you want help show what you have tried and give a precise description of what you want to achieve, and avoid external links.

Comment: You may find this anser [helpful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/guitar-tablatures-typesetting).